# Arduino Serial Communication not receiving entire message

Tags: serial-port, arduino, communication

I have a problem with the Arduino communication. It's quite hard to describe so I cant fit it in the title. Anyway here are the following:

So I have this code for my receiving end:

```
if(Serial1.available())
{
    while(Serial1.available())
    {
        uint8_t inByte = Serial1.read();

        inByte = inByte ^ k;

        Serial.write(inByte); 
    }

    Serial.println(" done");
}
```

It's supposed to print in one line and print done when it's done. The `Serial1.available()` seems to skip the next `Serial1.available()`, I don't know what's going on. Anyway here's my current, bad, output:

```
h done
e done
l done
l done
o done

done
```

when it should be:

```
hello done
```

I'm sorry if this could've been phrased better but that's all I can type now, my brain is kinda in pain.  I've never experienced this behavior in a Windows c++ console application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are calling that routine in loop() then yes, it will read from the serial buffer and immediately return since you are probably not sending the data fast enough.

A better way to handle this sort of thing is to use a control char which indicates the end of a message OR if you have a specific data format you expect to receive, then keep a count of the chars which have come in until the data format limit is reached.

There is discussion here which you may find useful: [Serial Duplex using Arduino](http://itp.nyu.edu/physcomp/Labs/SerialDuplex) Also there are example sketches that ship with the Arduino IDE: Menu: Examples: Communication:

Also, read all the entries under the [Serial](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/Serial) listing for Arduino. Good stuff there.

So the routine you develop for working with Serial input really depends on your project and the kind of data you are receiving. In your example above, if you were to use a control char, it might look like this:

```
 while(Serial1.available()){
   char c = Serial1.read();

   if (c == '*'){
       Serial.println(" done");
   } else {
       Serial.write(c); 
   } 
 }
```

Comment: thank you very much. I'm still a noob in the world of embedded systems such as arduino, i have been cradled by big architectures and framework like window for years I have forgotten the low levels.

Comment: Yup - I've pulled my hair out sometimes wrestling with serial stuff - like needing to receive large numbers. If you haven't already do check out the forums at http://arduino.cc/forum/ - huge community and very friendly. Cheers.